# Problemas con descarga de archivos web desde Python

Tags: python, web

Estoy intentando descargar la información de este [enlace](https://totoro.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Download&Format=excel2007&Extension=.xls&BypassCache=true&lang=es&path=%2Fshared%2FSeries%20Estad%C3%ADsticas_T%2F1.%20IPC%20base%202018%2F1.2.%20Por%20a%C3%B1o%2F1.2.4.IPC_Por%20ciudad_IQY), la cual contiene el histórico del IPC por ciudad en Colombia. Esto lo estoy tratando de hacer  mediante la ejecución del siguiente código

```
import urllib.request
dls = 'https://totoro.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Download&Format=excel2007&Extension=.xls&BypassCache=true&lang=es&path=%2Fshared%2FSeries%20Estad%C3%ADsticas_T%2F1.%20IPC%20base%202018%2F1.2.%20Por%20a%C3%B1o%2F1.2.4.IPC_Por%20ciudad_IQY'
outfilename = "test.xls"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(dls, outfilename)
```

Pero al abrir el archivo que se descarga aparece lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría descargar el archivo correctamente?

Comment: Es un página con Login, previo, dudo que con `request` lo consigas. Yo investigaría por el lado de https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/. De cualquier manera, no es algo sencillo como para responder. Con selenium básicamente puedes "simular" y automatizar la operación que harías manualmente, login, captura de datos, etc.